# How to run simple stored procedure in mysequel pro or mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I try to run this, but I get error.

```
set @var1 = 'AAA' ;
IF @var1 = 'AAA' THEN
Select * from List limit 2 
END IF;
```

I am trying to run this in MAC's MySequel Pro, or Mysql Workbench.

I get syntax error. Can't say why.

I am not very familiar with stored procedure syntax.

Google search also not helped.

Do I use a ; End BEGIN, ??? tried all, but no luck.

How is the syntax, when I should use ;

When I should use Begin and END ??

Appreciate your help.

Comment: It's not clear in your question, but are you even putting these in a procedure? You can't use `BEGIN`, `END`, or `IF/THEN` outside of a procedure or trigger.

Answer (score 0):

`IF @var1 == 'AAA' THEN` is wrong and so is the syntax error. It should just be below. Your's is not a compound statement and thus don't need a `Begin .. end` block. Refer [MySQL Documentation On IF Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html)

```
IF @var1 = 'AAA' THEN
Select * from List limit 2 
END IF;
```

Comment: @user1322977, *not working* has some reason. What's error message do you get ... post that.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF @var1 = 'AAA' THEN
Select * from List limit 2 
END IF' at line 1

Comment: Edit your question and post the entire code body to give a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL statement missing a semicolon at the end. It should be:
    Select * from List limit 2;

And this just for a sample of stored procedure:

```
delimiter $$

use `your_database`$$

drop procedure if exists `SP_Name`$$

create definer=`root`@`localhost` procedure `SP_Name`()
begin
    set @var1 = 'AAA';

    IF @var1 = 'AAA' THEN
        Select * from List limit 2;
    END IF;

end$$

delimiter ;
```

For more info, check [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) or [MySQL Stored Procedure Tutorial example](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx)